# Multiple conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created the javascript based demonstration and now I want to hide an image on click in certain condition only.

```
    $("#clear").click(function(){                
     if ($('#image').is(":visible") && ('#image2').is("hidden")) {
       $("#image").hide();
      }; 
    });
```

As you can see my code is not right, so I want to know how to format my code properly. I couldn't find the right way to write multiple conditions in one string. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you forget to add `$` (jQuery) to your second condition and selector `hidden` is incorrect, should be `:hidden`:

```
if ($('#image').is(":visible") && $('#image2').is(":hidden"))
```

Comment: @user3232377 don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful and welcome to SO.

Comment: sure, I'm just waiting for required minutes until I can accept the answer. ;) Thanks.